# Missing details of error handing in Documentation of Mongoose

Tags: mongoose

I am, on purpose, adding a duplicate user in using `model.save` to test a fail scenario. `Mongoose` correctly returns an error `{"index":0,"code":11000,"keyPattern":{"email":1},"keyValue":{"email":"email@email.com"}`

In the documenation however, I can't see where it is mentioned what error to expect - https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#Model.prototype.save()

Where can I find information about error handling of `mongoose`'s apis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mongoose has an [Error API](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/error.html#Error()):

> MongooseError constructor. MongooseError is the base class for all Mongoose-specific errors.

However, in Node.js development with mongoose it is common to implement `try/catch` and read the `err.code` to assert the type of error. In your case:

```js
 try {
        // If this fails for any reason it will throw to the catch block
        await model.save();
        // This will only return if the document was created successfully
        return res.status(200).json({
            message: 'saved'
        });
   } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
        // Check for the E11000 duplicate key error
        if(err.code === 11000){
            return res.status(400).json({
                message: err.message
            });
        }else{
            return res.status(500).json({
                message: 'Error on server'
           });
        }
   }
```

Comment: Thanks. Do I need to look in the code to see what type of error maps to `11000`?

Comment: If it's a validation error you can see what `kind` of error it is by accessing the the `error.kind` property. See [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html#validation-errors).

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Try and Catch Block` to handle errors returned by Mongoose.

Comment: I am doing that. My ask is where are `errors` defined in documentation so that I can see write code to handle them.